# Hyper-V guest crashes repeatedly

Tags: hyper-v

The host is Windows Server 2008 Datacenter, sp2. Version 6.0.6002
The hyper-V guest is XP, sp3.

I've been running 9 of these XP virtual machine for weeks with no problems. Today, one of them [xp1] started crashing. There was nothing in the XP event log about the crash. The Host event log (for Hyper-V-Worker) said this:

```
"Device 'VMBus' in 'XP1' cannot load because it is incompatible with virtualization stack. Server version 13 Client version 65537 (Virtual machine 'some guid').
```

Has anyone experienced this before or know how to solve it?
thanks,
dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the fact that I originally copied the VMs from another machine (windows server 2008 r2), which apparently has a newer version of Hyper-V that is slightly incompatible.  However, I would have expected these problems to occur weeks ago when I first copied them to the new machine, instead of just one or two failing all of a sudden yesterday.

Comment: That would explain it, and I would hope explain your trust issue regarding Hyper-V.  That said, the changes b/t Hyper-V R1 and R2 (2008 and 2008R2) are dramatic, taking Hyper-V from questionable to a very solid platform.  I would recommend simply finding some way to make your VM hosts 2008 R2

Comment: yeah, i was surprised to learn the two windows machines were different versions of windows, since they were supposed to be mirrors of each other. Anyways, I expected the VMs to be a little bit more encapsulated and portable. I've always been able to copy virtual pc and vmware images across different host systems..

Answer (score 0):

If this were my VM, I save an archival copy of the damaged VHD file and then (depending on how generic the VM was) I'd roll it back, restore it from backup, or replace it with a fresh image.  Given that this was a one-time event, is there a good reason to spend time and energy troubleshooting the specific problem?

Comment: 2 good reasons: 1--it's starting to happen for my other vms on that machine.  2--i need to know if i can trust hyper-v at all, or if i should switch providers.

Comment: Makes sense if it's more than one VM.